# WMPL get WooCommerce product category in a specific language

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

I am developing a WooCommerce multi language store using Wordpress 4.6, WPML 3.5, WooCommerce Multilingual 3.8.6 and WooCommerce version 2.6.4.

The code always return categories in the primary language but never returns the translation for the specified language.

Here is the code:-

```
    private $lang;

    function __construct($lang = "en") {
        $this->lang = $lang;
    }

    private function getCategories() {
        try {
                $api = WC()->api->WC_API_Products;
                $categories = $api->get_product_categories();

                $products_categories = $categories["product_categories"];

                foreach($products_categories as $category) {
                    $id = absint($category["id"]);
                    $category["name"] = $this->get_translated_term_name($id, "product_cat", $this->lang);
                }

                return $products_categories;

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                error_log("Caught $e");
            }
    }

    private function get_translated_term_name($term_id, $taxonomy, $language) {

        $translated_term_id = icl_object_id($term_id, $taxonomy, true, $language);

        $translated_term_object = get_term_by('id', $translated_term_id, $taxonomy);

        return $translated_term_object->name;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in this link:

https://wpml.org/forums/topic/how-to-get-the-translated-taxonomy-object/

It turned out that WPML adjusted ids of taxonomies automatically, so removing the filter before calling get_term solved the problem, here is the code:

```
    private function get_translated_term_name($term_id, $taxonomy, $language) {

        global $sitepress;
        remove_filter('get_term', array($sitepress,'get_term_adjust_id'), 1, 1);

        $translated_term_id = icl_object_id($term_id, $taxonomy, true, $language);

        $translated_term_object = get_term($translated_term_id, $taxonomy);

        add_filter('get_term', array($sitepress,'get_term_adjust_id'), 1, 1);

        return $translated_term_object->name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you might be surprised by the behavior of the get_term support function. Sometimes it doesn't return the term corresponding to the supplied term_id as input parameter but a cached result! So I rewrote it this way to bypass this.

```
private function getTerm($id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $id = absint($id);
    if(!$id) {
        return false;
    }
    $term = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->terms WHERE term_id=$id");
    return $term;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function wpa89819_wc_single_product(){

    $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );

    if ( $product_cats && ! is_wp_error ( $product_cats ) ){

        $single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats ); ?>

        <h2 itemprop="name" class="product_category_title"><span><?php echo $single_cat->name; ?></span></h2>

<?php }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wpa89819_wc_single_product', 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I don't want to use hooks and output the category to html, I want all categories as an array because it will be sent back as a json respone to an API request.